# Laravel 5 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, token, mismatch

I have created an easy PUT form for my site (also I have GET and POST forms, which work fine).

```
<h1>Edit {!! $brands->brand_name !!}</h1>

    <!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
    {!! Html::ul($errors->all()) !!}

    {!! Form::model($brands, array('route' => array('brands.update', $brands->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true)) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('brand_name', 'Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('brand_name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('brand_name_rus', 'Name_rus') !!}
        {!! Form::text('brand_name_rus', Input::old('brand_name_rus'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Your image') !!}
        <img src="http://parasha.dev/{{ $brands->img_brand_path }}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('img_brand_path', 'New image') !!}
        {!! Form::file('img_brand_path') !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Edit the Brand!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also I'm using Clip Two Theme as a layout of my admin panel that include those forms. And when I use both (layout and my forms, it gives me an arror -> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php). So this bootstrap theme somehow causes that error.

So I have two questions. First, how can I solve this problem. And the second, can I create laravel form without token autocreation? Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are not including the csrf_token in your form.

Add `{!! csrf_field() !!}` into your form. If you use ajax requests, you can place the `{!! csrf_field() !!}` in the 'master' template and reference it in the ajax header like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')}
});
```

Comment: This string create my token value. And in the inspector i found that value.  `{!! Form::model($brands, array('route' => array('brands.update', $brands->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true)) !!}` The problem isnt at form, my bootstrap theme causes that error!

Answer (score 0):

This works too :

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```